# Is there a difference between using the label for a p-button or putting the name between the tags

Tags: html, angular, primeng

Frontend-developement is pretty new to me and I have wondered if there is any difference between using:

```
<p-button label="OK"></p-button>
```

and

```
<p-button>OK</p-button>
```

Would be grateful for an explation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both do the same thing on the screen, but:

- The first method is more explicit than the second and is generally considered good practice.
- Screen readers and other assistive technology understand the first method for sure, but it is unlikely that all of them are able to understand the second one.